# FSM - Transitioning to another state

Tags: unity, fsm

I am using a Finite State Machine for my character who has the ability to change into various forms (Wolf, bird, ect).

[image]

The character changing to each state is not instantaneous and has a transition period to the next state. Most FSM i've seen set the next state instantaneously. My question is what should I do for the transitioning state? For example the "**HumanState**" is transitioning to the "**WolfState**" should I make another state class for each transition (Example: **HumanState** -> **HumanToWolfState** -> **WolfState**)? Or should I just have the state stay at the current state until the transition is done by using a coroutine and setting the state on completion?

Comment: Both solutions sound viable. How have you tried implementing it so far, and where specifically did you run into trouble that we can help you with?

Comment: Unless anything in particular came to mind that benefits also having a HumanToWolfState then I'd like option A better. But looks great Charles, very nice effect.